# SQL Server 2008 R2 isn't attaching a database file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server. The version is as follow:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (Intel X86)   Apr  2 2010 15:53:02
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition 
on Windows NT 5.2 <X86> (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

And when I try to attach `Callbacks.mdf` I get the following error:

> Attach database failed for Server 'LT122580\SQLEXPRESS'.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>   The database 'Egor_Callback' cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 655 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>   Could not open new database 'Egor_Callback'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)

I have no more available updates to SQL Server and I don't know what's causing this. Is it because I'm trying to attach it to SQL Server Express server? If so, How can I work around this problem without involving another server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The big problem here is the misconception that SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2 are the same thing. They're not. 2008 R2 is not just a service pack to 2008, it is a completely different version, and the database structures are different.

Your database came from a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance (661) but you are trying to install it on 2008 (which only supports up to 655). In some ways this is like trying to take the carburetor from your '67 Corvette and trying to install it in your '64 Corvette. They're probably close, but not identical.

In order to use your 2008 R2 instance on your local Express instance, you will need to upgrade or add a new 2008 R2 instance of SQL Server Express. You could even install SQL Server 2012, which will be able to use databases from 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, and 2012.

[Download SQL Server 2008 R2 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438)

[Download SQL Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579)

Comment: Thank you very much Aaron Bertrand :)